# How to map addresses with 10km radius bubble using R and tmap package

Tags: r, tmap

I have a list of addresses in San Diego county. I need to plot those on a map using R, and draw a 10 mile radius around each address.

Mapping the addresses as points is very easy using the tmap and tmaptools packages. But I can't figure out to draw a 10 mile radius around each location.

Using tm_shape and tm_dots, i added size = 0.9. So I can draw a circle, but I need it to be a 10 mile radius. I can't find any methods to do that with tmap and tmap_tools.

Does anyone know how to map a specified mile radius around a tm_dot?

This is my R code:

```
# Install packages ----
install.packages("tmap")
install.packages("tmaptools")
install.packages("readr")

# Load packages ----

library(tmap) # for making maps
library(tmaptools) # for the geocoding function
library(readr) # for reading in the csv file


# Import data ----

network_locations <- read_csv("clean_network_locations.csv")

# Geocoding addresses ----

coords3 <- geocode_OSM(q = network_locations$fullAddress, projection = 4326, as.sf = TRUE)

# Make map ----

tmap_mode("view")

#tm_shape with size
tm_shape(shp = coords3) +
  tm_dots(title=NA, legend.show=FALSE, size=0.9, id="", alpha=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create 10-mile buffers around points with `sf::st_buffer()` and then add those to `tmap` as a separate layer:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)

# generating points from example dataset
coords3 <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% 
  select(NAME) %>% 
  st_transform(4326) %>% 
  st_centroid()

# 10 mile buffers around points in coords3
buffers <- st_buffer(coords3, dist = units::set_units(10, mile))

tm_shape(shp = buffers) +
  tm_polygons(alpha = 0.5) +
  tm_shape(shp = coords3) +
  tm_dots(title=NA, legend.show=FALSE, size=0.2, id="", alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do this in `tmap` directly, but I'd do this by creating buffers using `sf` and then plot those buffers as a separate layer below the points. Here's what it looks like:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)

# create fake sample data
locations <- structure(list(query = c("82 Smith St, Providence, RI 02903", 
                         "194 Bellevue Ave, Newport, RI 02840", "24 Beacon St, Boston, MA 02133"
), lat = c(41.83089555, 41.4827777, 42.3326745972259), lon = c(-71.4149586644758, 
                                                               -71.3083749, -71.1593767838114)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

# convert the data to a sf object
random_points_sf <- st_as_sf(locations, coords = c("lon","lat"), crs= 4326)
```

Here's how to make ten mile buffers. What you specify as the distance depends on what projection you are using. I'm pretty sure 4326 uses meters, so I converted 10 miles to meters

```
# 10 miles in meters is 16093.4 
# according to google
buffers <- st_buffer(random_points_sf, 16093.4)
```

Here's the plotting step

```
tmap_mode("view")


tm_shape(buffers)+
  tm_polygons(alpha = 0.5,
              col = "green")+
tm_shape(shp = random_points_sf) +
  tm_dots(title=NA, legend.show=FALSE,  id="", alpha=1, col = "red")
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]